# Android block user to use Application

Tags: android

I have develop application that provide user to find nearby place based on Google Maps. User which want to use my application must register using their Google Accounts before to use my application and login using their account. After user has successfully login in my application, my application save some Shared Preferences to indicate user has logged in. So, after that, user no need to login again.

My application have many activity and fragment inside.  After some time, i want add blocking feature to user. If user has blocked, they cannot using my application again until administrator unblocking its account. So, administrator can blocking user account from web server. Administrator can block user while user use my application. So i need a real time system blocking.

I need some idea that simply to implemented on my application. My application contains many activity and fragment. If the idea is check user account in every activity and fragment to database server, i think its bad idea. Because i can consume user's bandwidth and and gives a lot of work for me. I need some idea that provide blocking system in real time.

So if user has been blocked, they cannot use my application :

1. even they were using application.
2. Even when they tried to close application and opened again
3. Even when they tried to clear application data in Settings/Application Manager/My App/Clear Data
4. Even they on another application and back to my application (onResume ())
5. Or even they uninstall application and download it from Play Store.

Any Idea? Please provide some code or links for reference.

Thanks.

Comment: Why it need to be close? whats wrong? I need some idea here. Where i must ask my problem beside in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a `boolean isBlocked` somewhere in your code. [**Here is a simple example**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)

In the `onCreate` on the launch activity, you reads this value from your server (so each time the app gets turned on) and check its value. Each time you read this value you can also store it in the `SharedPreferences` as `lastKnownIsBlockedValue` and then read this value if the user has no internet connection. This way, if you block the user and they turn off the internet, they are still blocked.

Also, if the user is blocked, inside `onCreate()` and after the check, you can launch another activity telling him "You are blocked" or something along those lines. Otherwise you can continue with the normal flow of your app.

All your cases are covered this way and its pretty simple:

> Even if they were using application.

Since you read data from the server each time the app loads, doesn't matter how long they were using the app, once they get blocked they are blocked.

> Even when they tried to close application and opened again

Same reason as above plus you can use the value stored in `SharedPreferences` if they disconnect from the internet.

> Even when they tried to clear application data in Settings/Application Manager/My App/Clear Data

Same reason as the first one if they have internet. However, if you block them and they disconnect from the internet, and press Clear Data there might be a problem. If they manage to delete stuff stored in the `SharedPreferences` they will become unblocked but only while they stay disconnected from the internet. Honestly, I am not sure how Clear Data works and does it delete `SharedPreferences` so I am sure somebody else here will fill in the blanks here :)

> Even they on another application and back to my application (onResume ())

This works because, once `onCreate()` is called and you determine the user is blocked, you launch the second activity that just tells them "Sorry you are blocked" or whatever so the `onResume()` will be called for that activity and not your regular one.

> Or even they uninstall application and download it from Play Store.

Same reasoning as the first one. You blocked user's are saved online so you are fine even if they re-install the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging). Please Read  [this](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Idea is that. when admin will send push to user to block. The receive on you app will receive block push via GCM. On receive method you can close your app or you can give popup to block. and also logout user so when he login again app will check block status for that user on server.

And when admin wants to unblock user then just change block status on server to UNBLOCK